# Excell VBA read and write Folder Subfolder and its files

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Folder, subfolders and its files. Files are named like Subfodlername-testType(11203-bcst). I want to take data from files in a subfolder according to testType name and write data in an excelform and save automaticlly. Do theese for every subfolders with loop. can I do it with VBA ?

```
Function Recurse(sPath As String) As String

Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim myFolder As Folder
Dim mySubFolder As Folder
Dim myFile As File
Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sPath)
Dim s As String

For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders
    For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files
        If InStr(myFile, "bcst") > 0 Then

            Dim sItem2 As String
            Dim sItem3 As String
            Dim sItem4 As String
            Dim sItem5 As String
            Dim sItem6 As String
            Dim sItem7 As String


            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Set ana = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sayfa1") 'Hangi sayfaya alınacak?
            Set dosya = Workbooks.Open(sPath) 'Alınacak dosyanın uzantısı ne?


            sItem2 = dosya.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("A4")
            Dim indexOfChar As Integer
            indexOfChar = InStr(1, sItem2, ":")
            Dim finalString As String
            finalString = Right(sItem2, Len(sItem2) - indexOfChar)
            ana.Range("F7") = finalString & "." 'Hangi sayfanın hangi hücresi nereye alınacak?


            sItem3 = dosya.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("A5")
            Dim indexOfChar2 As Integer
            indexOfChar2 = InStr(1, sItem3, ":")
            Dim finalString2 As String
            finalString2 = Right(sItem3, Len(sItem3) - indexOfChar2)
            MsgBox finalString
            ana.Range("F8") = finalString2 'Hangi sayfanın hangi hücresi nereye alınacak?

            sItem4 = dosya.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("A7")
            Dim indexOfChar3 As Integer
            indexOfChar3 = InStr(1, sItem4, ":")
            Dim finalString3 As String
            finalString3 = Right(sItem4, Len(sItem4) - indexOfChar3)
            ana.Range("F9") = finalString3 'Hangi sayfanın hangi hücresi nereye alınacak?

            sItem5 = dosya.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("A6")
            Dim indexOfChar4 As Integer
            indexOfChar4 = InStr(1, sItem5, ":")
            Dim finalString4 As String
            finalString4 = Right(sItem5, Len(sItem5) - indexOfChar4)
            ana.Range("F10") = finalString4 'Hangi sayfanın hangi hücresi nereye alınacak?

            sItem6 = dosya.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("A8")
            Dim indexOfChar5 As Integer
            indexOfChar5 = InStr(1, sItem6, ":")
            Dim finalString5 As String
            finalString5 = Right(sItem6, Len(sItem6) - indexOfChar5)
            ana.Range("F11") = finalString5 'Hangi sayfanın hangi hücresi nereye alınacak?


            sItem7 = dosya.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("A11")
            Dim indexOfChar6 As Integer
            indexOfChar6 = InStr(1, sItem7, ":")
            Dim finalString6 As String
            finalString6 = Right(sItem7, Len(sItem7) - indexOfChar6)
            ana.Range("F12") = finalString6 'Hangi sayfanın hangi hücresi nereye alınacak?






            dosya.Close
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True

            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Recurse = Recurse(mySubFolder.Path)
Next

End Function
```

---

```
Sub TestR()

    Call Recurse(GetFolder)

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes it is possible have you tried anything?

Comment: You can. But if you want any help achieving it, you need to show us what you have tried so far and explain where you got stuck in the process.

Comment: I tried yeap but its not working actually.

Answer (score 0):

What if there are subfolders in your subfolders?

Try this for looping through the files instead:

```
Sub LoopFromFolder(ByVal folderName As String)

    Dim file As Variant

    For Each file In Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & folderName & "\*.*"" /S /A:-D /B").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), "bcst")
        '// Your code here
    Next
End Sub
```

This will loop through all files in all subfolders of `folderName` that contain "bcst" in the file name and is much quicker than using recursion with the `FileSystemObject`

Comment: I have a folder and it has 250 folder and each of them have four files in it I want to iterate folder by folder and in each folder I read files and save an excel and go another folder. This is not help me I think

Comment: There is no subfolders I have main folder subfolders and files

Comment: This will still work even with only single sets of subfolders and is still quicker than using the `FileSystemObject`

Comment: Yes, the code I have supplied will only loop through the files that have "bcst" in the file name

Comment: But I need different things. I have a main folder and subfolders in every sub folder there are 4 file like (123-bcst  , 123-pcpt , 123-corsi, 123-wcst) I want to take data from theese files and bcst data will be write book1 sheet1 A4 and pcpt data will write A5. after for files is ok pass the other subfolder. Can I do that ?

Comment: That's not what you've asked in your question, and your original code only looks as files with "bcst" in the name. You should update your original question and make it clear what you are trying to achieve.